# Add items to basket and store in localStorage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I want to create an action for the button to be able to add items to the basket and keep data in localStorage. I'm struggling with push items when the basket has already more than one item inside. I can easily increase the quantity of existing items if an ID is same but can't add new items. Data I'm getting from JSON file. JSON contains only five unique IDs. Below part of my code.

```
AddBtn.addEventListener('click', function (add) {               //Add item to when click AddBtn localStorage 
            add.preventDefault() // Avoid default action.
    
           const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));   // Parse data from localstorage
    
            let elementimageUrl = element.imageUrl;                     // element.imageUrl is a part of backend data received from JSON file
            let elementId = element._id;                                // element._id is a part of backend data received from JSON file
            let elementName = element.name;                             // element.name is a part of backend data received from JSON file
            let elementPrice = element.price;                           // element.price is a part of backend data received from JSON file
            let elementQuantity = 1;

                if(basket === undefined || basket.length > 4 ){
                    //Existing data block in local storage
                    basket.forEach(product => {
                        if (product.elementId === elementId) {
                            product.elementQuantity++
                            console.log('increase');
                        }
                    });
                } else{
                  //Non Exist data block in local storage
                  basket.push({elementId, elementName, elementPrice, elementQuantity, elementimageUrl});    // Push not existing data to localstorage
                    console.log('add')
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution for your problem.

```
AddBtn.addEventListener('click', function (add) {               //Add item to when click AddBtn localStorage
  add.preventDefault() // Avoid default action.

  let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));   // Parse data from localstorage

  let elementimageUrl = element.imageUrl;                     // element.imageUrl is a part of backend data received from JSON file
  let elementId = element._id;                                // element._id is a part of backend data received from JSON file
  let elementName = element.name;                             // element.name is a part of backend data received from JSON file
  let elementPrice = element.price;                           // element.price is a part of backend data received from JSON file
  let elementQuantity = 1;

  if (!basket) {
    basket = [];
  }

  // find the index of the item if already in basket
  const itemIndexInBasket = basket.findIndex(basketEntry => basketEntry.elementId === elementId);
  if (itemIndexInBasket !== -1) {
    basket[itemIndexInBasket].elementQuantity++;
  } else {
    basket.push({elementId, elementName, elementPrice, elementQuantity, elementimageUrl});    // Push not existing data to localstorage
  } 
  localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a jsfiddle link with dummy values for variables? It will be a lot easier to debug.
Seeing the above explanation that you are facing a problem with push items I assumed this below data and it is working.

```
const basket = [{abc:"1"},{abcs:'3'}];
let elementimageUrl = 'abc';
let elementId = 1;                               
let elementName = 'a';                             
let elementPrice = 10;                           
let elementQuantity = 1;

     
basket.push({elementId, elementName, elementPrice, elementQuantity, elementimageUrl});    
console.log('add')
console.log(basket);
localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
```